# C segmentation fault, can anybody help me identify why?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am using the following code to split a char array in C:

```
    char line[100];
int number_of_gga_parsed = 0;
int gga_blocks_allocated;
    gga_sentence *ggas_parsed;
    gsa_sentence gsa;
    gsv_sentence gsv;


    ggas_parsed = malloc(10*sizeof(gga_sentence));
    gga_blocks_allocated = 10;

    if(ggas_parsed == NULL){

        printf("error allocating memory, system exiting.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while(fscanf(stream, "%s", line)!= EOF){

    strcpy((ggas_parsed + number_of_gga_parsed)->untouched_sentence, line);

    initiate_gga_values((ggas_parsed + number_of_gga_parsed),(ggas_parsed + number_of_gga_parsed)->untouched_sentence);
```

}

initiate_gga_values function:

```
void initiate_gga_values(gga_sentence* gga_ptr, const char* sentence){

    char *temp_sentence;
    char *token;
    int token_no = 0;

    /*Copy the gga_sentence into the temp_sentence char array*/
    strcpy(temp_sentence, sentence);


    token = strsep (temp_sentence,",");

    while (token != NULL) {
        switch(token_no){
        case 0:
            gga_ptr->sentence_id = token;
            break;
        case 1:
            /*atoi converts a string to an int, well a c string anyways so a char* */
            gga_ptr->time_stamp = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 2:
            /*strtod coverts a string to a double, well a c string anyways so a char* */
            gga_ptr->latitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 3:
            gga_ptr->north_south_id = (char)token;
            break;
        case 4:
            gga_ptr->longitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 5:
            gga_ptr->east_west_id = (char)token;
            break;
        case 6:
            gga_ptr->quality = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 7:
            gga_ptr->no_of_satellites = atoi(token);
            break;
        case 8:
            gga_ptr->horizontal_dillution = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 9:
            gga_ptr->altitude = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 10:
            gga_ptr->altitude_units = (char)token;
            break;
        case 11:
            gga_ptr->geodial_seperation = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 12:
            gga_ptr->geodial_seperation_units = (char)token;
            break;
        case 13:
            gga_ptr->age_of_data_in_seconds = strtod(token, NULL);
            break;
        case 14:
            gga_ptr->checksum = token;
            break;
        }
        token_no++;
        token = strsep (temp_sentence, ",");

         }
}
```

The char array consists of this information:

```
$GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,51.1,M,,0000*72
```

but when the code in run on the above, i get a segmentation fault:

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

gga struct:

```
typedef struct gga_sentence{

    char untouched_sentence[100];
    gsa_sentence gsa;
    char *sentence_id;
    int time_stamp;
    double latitude;
    char north_south_id;
    double longitude;
    char east_west_id;
    int quality;
    int no_of_satellites;
    double horizontal_dillution;
    double altitude;
    char altitude_units;
    double geodial_seperation;
    char geodial_seperation_units;
    double age_of_data_in_seconds;
    char *checksum;

}gga_sentence;
```

**The segmentation fault happens before the function initiate_gga_values function completes, or even starts really. This means i assume there is a problem with the mallocing of gga_sentences but i cannot see where!**

This is the first time i am using strsep, so no doubt i am doing something very wrong.

**gdb error message:**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7de4103 in _dl_lookup_symbol_x (undef_name=0x4004d8 "strlen", undef_map=0x7ffff7ffe268, 
    ref=ref@entry=0x7fffffffdbb8, symbol_scope=0x302e312c362e312c, version=0x7ffff7ff9a08, 
    type_class=type_class@entry=1, flags=1, skip_map=skip_map@entry=0x0) at dl-lookup.c:733
733 dl-lookup.c: No such file or directory.
```

Cheers,
Chris.

Comment: What is `gga_ptr`? How are you initializing it?

Comment: sorry i thought i added that! ill add it now!

Comment: to me `    strcpy((ggas_parsed + number_of_gga_parsed)->untouched_sentence, line);` looks dubious. What are you trying here using `number_of_gga_parsed` ?

Comment: @brokenfoot the idea is, because you dont know the number of gga_sentences in the file i keep track of how many ive read, then use pointer addition to locate where i want it stored so initially number_of_gga_parsed = 0 so (ggas_parsed + number_of_gga_parsed) should point to index 0 in the mallocd memory, when number_of_gga_parsed = 10, i want the 10th index in the malloc'd memory.

Comment: Just for precaution, check for NULL pointer while accessing `gga_ptr->sentence_id = token;`, put a `if(NULL==gga_ptr) {//handle the error}`

Comment: Could we see the `gga_sentence` structure definition?

Comment: @brokenfoot i tried that, the condition was never met so i dont think it is null :/ i have added the gga_sentence struct now

Answer (score 3):

```
char *temp_sentence;
char *token;
int token_no = 0;

/*Copy the gga_sentence into the temp_sentence char array*/
strcpy(temp_sentence, sentence);
```

You aren't allocating any memory for temp_sentence to hold the copied string

Comment: i added this line: temp_sentence = malloc(sizeof(sentence)); just abov e the strcpy line and still a seg fault :/

Comment: `sizeof(sentence)` is the size of a pointer, maybe 8 bytes. You'll need `strlen(sentence) + 1` here. (The extra byte holds the null character at the end.) Or you could use `temp_sentence = strdup(sentence)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
token = strsep (&temp_sentence,",");
```

`strsep` takes `char**` as first argument.

Comment: is your `temp_sentence` long enough? have you tried making it bigger?

Comment: i changed it to a char* and still the same problem.

Comment: @chrisedwards try with char[1000] if it holds

Comment: on further debugging, ive noticed that the segfault happens before strsep is reached, i guess its a memory allocation error.

Comment: @chrisedwards my guess is `temp_sentence` can't hold your `const char*`

Comment: Run it with a debugger. The debugger will tell you where exactly it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

You are copying `sentence` to uninitialised memory:

```
char *temp_sentence;

/* ... */

strcpy(temp_sentence, sentence);
```

`temp_sentence` is an uninitialised pointer that points to some random place, but not to any extra memory. To fix this, you could allocate a certain amount of chars on the stack, say:

```
char temp_sentence[100];

strncpy(temp_sentence, sentence, sizeof(temp_sentence) - 1);
```

This might cut your string short. An alternative is to allocate a duplicate of the input string on the heap:

```
char *temp_sentence = strdup(sentence);
```

In that case you must free the allocated memory with `free(temp_sentence)` before returning from the function. In either case, you'll need a second pointer that you can pass to `strsep`:

```
char *ptr = temp_sentence;
```

This pointer needs to be modifiable, so you can't use an array. If the temporary string is allocated with `strdup` you need to retain the original pointer so you can free your memory.

**Edit**: As already noted by Arjun Sreedharan, you should pass a pointer to a pointer to char as a first parameter to `strsep`. That way, the pointer gets updated and refers to the rest of the string that hasn't been parsed yet.

A mismatch of pointer types should really give a warning message. Have you enabled warnings?

Anyway, here's a short working example of what you want to do, but without the actual parsing:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    const char* sentence = "$GPGGA,151019.000,5225.9627,N,"
                            "00401.1624,W,1,09,1.0,38.9,M,"
                            "51.1,M,,0000*72";

    char *tmp = strdup(sentence);   // modifiable copy
    char *p = tmp;                  // pointer into copy for strsep
    char *token;
    int token_no = 0;

    token = strsep(&p, ",");
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%d: '%s'\n", token_no, token);
        token_no++;
        token = strsep(&p, ",");
    }

    free(tmp);                      // release ressources of copy
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ive added what you said, i still get a seg fault.

Comment: The crash happens somewhere in the system functions. Get a traceback with `where` and look in which of _your_ functions the crash happens. Be sure to compile with `-g` so that you get symbol names and line numbers. Anyway, I reckon that your crashes are a combination of everything other posters and I have mentioned. I've added a working framework from which you can start.

Comment: The problem is to do with the malloc of the gga_sentence memory, i have removed line after line and it throws an seg fault when i use that memory. ill look into the problem now.